# How to get the src from image in jquery

Tags: jquery, image, src

i have 3 images with the same id="UserImages" i wanted to know if i can click on them and get the scr in jquery?

Comment: An html id attribute cannot have the same value multiple times.  Use class attribute.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First I'd switch them to classes (IDs must be unqiue):

```
<img class="UserImages" src="..." />
```

Then use [a `.class` selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) to find them, like this:

```
$("img.UserImages").click(function() {
  alert(this.src);
});
```

Comment: how would i get only the file name not the whole address?

Comment: @Gully - There's a few easy options for that, check out these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605696/get-file-name-from-url, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302306/how-to-pull-the-file-name-from-a-url-using-javascript-jquery