# How to obtain the last path segment of a URI

Tags: java, string, url

I have as input a string that is a `URI`. how is it possible to get the last path segment (that in my case is an id)?

This is my input URL:

```
String uri = "http://base_path/some_segment/id"
```

and I have to obtain the id I have tried with this:

```
String strId = "http://base_path/some_segment/id";
strId = strId.replace(path);
strId = strId.replaceAll("/", "");
Integer id =  new Integer(strId);
return id.intValue();
```

but it doesn't work, and surely there must be a better way to do it.

Comment: The method `getLastPathSegment ` doesn't work with `:` in Android 6.0

Answer (score 218, accepted):

is that what you are looking for:

```
URI uri = new URI("http://example.com/foo/bar/42?param=true");
String path = uri.getPath();
String idStr = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
int id = Integer.parseInt(idStr);
```

alternatively

```
URI uri = new URI("http://example.com/foo/bar/42?param=true");
String[] segments = uri.getPath().split("/");
String idStr = segments[segments.length-1];
int id = Integer.parseInt(idStr);
```

Comment: I was searching for Android's android.net.Uri (not java.net.URI) and ended up here. If you're using that instead, there's a method there called getLastPathSegment() which should do the same thing. :)

Comment: Just do `String idStr = new File(uri.getPath()).getName()`, same as this answer but uses `File` instead of `String` to split the path.

Comment: this wont work for urls like http://example.com/job/senior-health-and-nutrition-advisor/?param=true. Last "/" is making trouble. Need something more good getLastPathSegment() answer given by @paul_sns  is perfect.

Comment: @VaibhavKadam well, technically you could argue that the last segment is an empty string. But if that's not what you want simply use: `while (path.endsWith("/")) path = path.substring(0, path.length() - 1);`

Comment: @sfussenegger My bad I didn't read TAGs in question. I thought it has tag of android. Well +1 for android.net.uri. :). Android is taking over JAVA.

Comment: Used it for SQS queue name extraction. The native implementation does not have simple method for it. It only returns queue URLs.

Answer (score 82):

```
import android.net.Uri;
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://example.com/foo/bar/42?param=true");
String token = uri.getLastPathSegment();
```

Comment: Is this "android.net.Uri"?  Base don the tags of the question, java.net.URI would be assumed and it doesn't have a getLastPathSegment()...

Comment: Also, the Android `Uri` class name is lowercase and cannot be instantiated. I've corrected your answer to use the static factory method `Uri.parse()`.

Comment: GetLastPathSegment doesn't exists here.

Comment: it does have getLastPathSegment() but it doesn't work! returns null!

Comment: Seems like getLastPathSegment() randomly spits out the full path for me.

Comment: @MobDev Can you provide any examples?

Answer (score 55):

Here's a short method to do it:

```
public static String getLastBitFromUrl(final String url){
    // return url.replaceFirst("[^?]*/(.*?)(?:\\?.*)","$1);" <-- incorrect
    return url.replaceFirst(".*/([^/?]+).*", "$1");
}
```

Test Code:

```
public static void main(final String[] args){
    System.out.println(getLastBitFromUrl(
        "http://example.com/foo/bar/42?param=true"));
    System.out.println(getLastBitFromUrl("http://example.com/foo"));
    System.out.println(getLastBitFromUrl("http://example.com/bar/"));
}
```

Output:

> 42
>   foo
>   bar

Explanation:

```
.*/      // find anything up to the last / character
([^/?]+) // find (and capture) all following characters up to the next / or ?
         // the + makes sure that at least 1 character is matched
.*       // find all following characters


$1       // this variable references the saved second group from above
         // I.e. the entire string is replaces with just the portion
         // captured by the parentheses above
```

Comment: while i am a big fan of regex and use it frequently myself, i recognize that for most developers, regex is about as obtuse as it gets. it is not simpler in the fact that it is not quickly understood.

Comment: The `/` in the negated character class `[^/?]` is unnecessary, because it will never be matched. `.*/` will always match the **last** `/` in the String, so no other `/` should be encountered.

Comment: doesn't work for this kind of link ``http://example.com/foo#reply2``, It will be great if you could update your answer to solve it. Thanks

Comment: @Seth I have just tried this myself; if you update the regular expression to ```([^#/?]+)``` instead of ```([^/?]+)``` that should work.

Answer (score 29):

I know this is old, but the solutions here seem rather verbose. Just an easily readable one-liner if you have a `URL` or `URI`:

```
String filename = new File(url.getPath()).getName();
```

Or if you have a `String`:

```
String filename = new File(new URL(url).getPath()).getName();
```

Comment: Does it work with all possible options of a URL, like `a.co/last?a=1#frag`. I think not, as the code does substring of the last path symbol until the end: `path.substring(index + 1)`.

Comment: @alik The question asks for the last path segment. The query and fragment are not part of the path segment.

Answer (score 17):

If you are using Java 8 and you want the last segment in a file path you can do.

```
Path path = Paths.get("example/path/to/file");
String lastSegment = path.getFileName().toString();
```

If you have a url such as `http://base_path/some_segment/id` you can do.

```
final Path urlPath = Paths.get("http://base_path/some_segment/id");
final Path lastSegment = urlPath.getName(urlPath.getNameCount() - 1);
```

Comment: Risky because java.nio.file.Paths#get depends on OS filesystem the JVM is running on. There's no guarantee it will recognise a URI with forward slashes as path separators.

Comment: What about URI with query params? Treating a random URI as a file system path is asking for an exception.

Answer (score 15):

**In Android**

Android has a built in class for managing URIs.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://base_path/some_segment/id");
String lastPathSegment = uri.getLastPathSegment()
```

Comment: Sometimes this just spits out the full path. Not sure why or when it seems to be random.

Comment: If you can catch the content it's parsing, maybe you can set up a unit test to make sure.

Answer (score 11):

If you have `commons-io` included in your project, you can do it without creating unecessary objects with `org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils`

```
String uri = "http://base_path/some_segment/id";
String fileName = FilenameUtils.getName(uri);
System.out.println(fileName);
```

Will give you the last part of the path, which is the `id`

Answer (score 8):

In Java 7+ a few of the previous answers can be combined to allow retrieval of *any* path segment from a URI, rather than just the last segment. We can convert the URI to a [`java.nio.file.Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) object, to take advantage of its [`getName(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#getName(int)) method.

Unfortunately, the static factory `Paths.get(uri)` is not built to handle the http scheme, so we first need to separate the scheme from the URI's path.

```
URI uri = URI.create("http://base_path/some_segment/id");
Path path = Paths.get(uri.getPath());
String last = path.getFileName().toString();
String secondToLast = path.getName(path.getNameCount() - 2).toString();
```

To get the last segment in one line of code, simply nest the lines above.

`Paths.get(URI.create("http://base_path/some_segment/id").getPath()).getFileName().toString()`

To get the second-to-last segment while avoiding index numbers and the potential for off-by-one errors, use the [`getParent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#getParent()) method.

`String secondToLast = path.getParent().getFileName().toString();`

Note the `getParent()` method can be called repeatedly to retrieve segments in reverse order. In this example, the path only contains two segments, otherwise calling `getParent().getParent()` would retrieve the third-to-last segment.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use replaceAll:

```
String uri = "http://base_path/some_segment/id"
String lastSegment = uri.replaceAll(".*/", "")

System.out.println(lastSegment);
```

result:

```
id
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `getPathSegments()` function. ([Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#getPathSegments()))

Consider your example URI:

```
String uri = "http://base_path/some_segment/id"
```

You can get the last segment using:

```
List<String> pathSegments = uri.getPathSegments();
String lastSegment = pathSegments.get(pathSegments.size() - 1);
```

`lastSegment` will be `id`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the last DIR path segment:

```
Paths.get(path).getParent().getFileName();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following in a utility class:

```
public static String lastNUriPathPartsOf(final String uri, final int n, final String... ellipsis)
  throws URISyntaxException {
    return lastNUriPathPartsOf(new URI(uri), n, ellipsis);
}

public static String lastNUriPathPartsOf(final URI uri, final int n, final String... ellipsis) {
    return uri.toString().contains("/")
        ? (ellipsis.length == 0 ? "..." : ellipsis[0])
          + uri.toString().substring(StringUtils.lastOrdinalIndexOf(uri.toString(), "/", n))
        : uri.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get list of path segments from the Uri class

```
String id = Uri.tryParse("http://base_path/some_segment/id")?.pathSegments.last ?? "InValid URL";
```

It will return id if the url is valid, if it is invalid it returns "Invalid url"

Answer (score -1):

Get URL from URI and use getFile() if you are not ready to use substring way of extracting file.

Comment: won't work, see javadoc of getFile(): Gets the file name of this URL. The returned file portion will be the same as getPath(), plus the concatenation of the value of getQuery(), if any. If there is no query portion, this method and getPath() will return identical results.)

Comment: Use `getPath()` not `getFile()`.