# Obtain name from absolute path, substring from last slash, java android

Tags: java, android, file

I want to extract the name of an absolute path. If I have a string with the value /mnt/sdcard/Videos/Videoname, I want to save a string with the value Videoname.

The string is changing and I can't obtain previously the number of slashes. How could I split a substring from the last slash?

> /mnt/sdcard/Videos/Videoname --> Videnoname

Comment: String name = "/mnt/sdcard/Videos/Videoname";
String newName = name.substring(name.lastIndexOf("/")+1, name.length());

Comment: Follow this link to an answered question similar to yours. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050087/how-to-obtain-the-last-path-segment-of-an-uri#

Answer (score 25):

You should go via the [`File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) api. Quoted from the [`File.getName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getName%28%29) documentation:

> Returns the name of the file or directory denoted by this abstract pathname. This is just the last name in the pathname's name sequence. If the pathname's name sequence is empty, then the empty string is returned.

Example:

```
String name = new File("/mnt/sdcard/Videos/Videoname").getName();
```

Answer (score 16):

If you got if from a "File" object, you can get it with the method:

```
String fileName = myFile.getName();
```

If you got it from a simple String, you can use

```
String fileName = myString.substring(myString.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
```

Comment: -1. The string version is wrong, `"/mnt/sdcard/Videos/Videoname"` would return `"/Videoname"`. Use the `File` API as I suggested, e.g. new File("/mnt/sdcard/Videos/Videoname").getName() which would return the correct `"Videoname"`.

Comment: You're right, I forgot to add +1 to the index...
But, for sure, the "File" version is waaaay nicer ;)

Answer (score 7):

```
String path = "/mnt/sdcard/Videos/Videoname"; // Your path

String fileName = new File(path).getName(); // you file name
```

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is

```
String path ="AnyDirectory/subFolder/last.htm";
int pos = path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1;

path.substring(pos, path.length()-pos);
```

Now you have the last.htm in the path string.

Answer (score 1):

But with a little more research, the following code works...

```
String[] Tokens = stringPath.split("\\\\");
```

You need to escape the "\" twice.

Comment: Actually the question was about forward slashes `/` rather than backslashes `\ `.

Answer (score 0):

```
string a = "/foo/bar/target";
string words = a.Split("/")
string target = words[words.length-1]
```