# I want to write a java code, parse the last number from the URL.Then I need to check if that number is present in a excel. else If present return

Tags: java

I want to write a java code, that will basically parse the last number from the URL. Then I need to check, if that number is present in a excel. If not found  show an error, else If present return me the row name.

Say URL: *http://foxsd5174:3887/PD/outage/area/v1/device/40122480*
and from the below excel I need to know, "40122480" falls under which category city or county?

```
                 City        County     Event Level 
  Device ID     40122480    277136436   268698851
```

to fetch value from URL i was thing of using the below code.

Please help me out.

Comment: public static void main(final String[] args){
    System.out.println(getLastBitFromUrl(
        "http://foxsd5174:3887/PD/outage/area/v1/device/40122480?param=true"));
}

Comment: Put the code in the question, not in the comments, what's the format of the file? xls? TSV? excel is a very broad file type

Comment: There is no actual question here.  Please show us what the code you have written so far, and explain in detail the specific problem that is blocking you.  Note that there are lots of Q&As, tutorials, etc on how to read an Excel spreadsheet in Java.  So a general "how do I do it" is best answered with a Google search

Comment: Please read "[ask]", then [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] of a _specific_ problem you've encountered.

Answer (score 0):

Use this post in case you don't know how to get the last number of the url:
[How to obtain the last path segment of an uri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050087/how-to-obtain-the-last-path-segment-of-an-uri)

To read the excel file use this tutorial https://www.callicoder.com/java-read-excel-file-apache-poi/ which uses **[apache poi](https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/poi/release/src/poi-src-3.17-20170915.zip)** library to get the job done.

Just compare the cell value with the last number of the url.

Comment: look i need to go for get request for several URL. Where I need to parse the last bit of the URL and validate that the number is indeed present in the database(as of now its excel).  or validate JSON to say if it is valid response if yes return  city or county name {  
   "etrTimestamp":"04/10/2018 23:45:00",
   "eventName":"Kenny",
   "eventType":"Hurricane",
   "areaName":"Palm Beach",
   "areaType":"County",
   "serviceStatus":{  
      "additionalInfo":"Area ETR Present",
      "resultStatusCode":"200",
      "resultStatusMessage":"SUCCESS"
   }

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the number of digits at the end of the URL you could parse it in multiple different ways. You could use regex, or substrings. To compare it to an excel file you could first convert the excel file into a csv (They are compatible) use BufferedReader along with FileReader to read in the file. Make an array of strings and using regex or any parsing method separate out the commas within the csv file you created. Then simply run a while loop that loops to EOF and check for the string you've parsed being "40122480" using the equals() method on type string and seeing if your string matches any of the strings you've just parsed from the file.

EDITED*

Rough and quick code I did in a few minutes to maybe help the parsing thing for you.

```
String parsedUrl[] = new String[8];
       String url = "http://foxsd5174:3887/PD/outage/area/v1/device/40122480";
       System.out.println(url);
       parsedUrl = url.split("/");
       System.out.println(parsedUrl[8]);
```

Comment: The below code return me URL Last digit. now  compare it in my excel, and return the row name.                  
                            City      County  Event Level 
  Device ID     40122480    2771   8851    public class smartoutage {
 public static void main(final String[] args){
     System.out.println(getLastBitFromUrl(
         "http://goxsd5174:3807/device/40122480?param=true"));
 }
public static String getLastBitFromUrl(final String url){
    // return url.replaceFirst("[^?]*/(.*?)(?:\\?.*)","$1);" <-- incorrect
    return url.replaceFirst(".*/([^/?]+).*", "$1");
}
}

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the below code to get the last digit of the URL.

```
public class smartoutage {
    public static void main(final String[] args){
    System.out.println(getLastBitFromUrl(
    "http://goxsd5174:3807/PD/outage/areaEtr/v1/device/40122480?param=true"));
    }
    public static String getLastBitFromUrl(final String url){
    return url.replaceFirst(".*/([^/?]+).*", "$1");
    }
    }
```

Output is 40122480
now i need to find if 40122480 is present in the excel and return me the row name for which it belong
                 City        County     Event Level 
  Device ID     40122480    277136436   268698851

Comment: please help me with the 2nd part . that is compare the result wit excel and fetch the row