# Trim last part of a URL in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I need to trim last part of a URL in Clojure. Like I have `http://example.com/file.html` and  I need to get `file.html` out. How to do it in Clojure?

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach uses the standard library that ships with the JVM, so you don't need any extra libraries:

```
(-> "http://example.com/file.html" java.net.URL. .getPath java.io.File. .getName)
;;=> "file.html"
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4050114/1008794) which may be relevant.

Comment: You linked to the right answer, but summarized it wrong. URL is a legacy class that for most cases should be considered a toxic waste dump. Very strongly prefer using URI, as does the answer you linked to.

Comment: @Rulle It's the same thing as you've used just replace java.net.URL with java.net.URI