# How to fetch pattern matcher groups for repetitive regex pattern in Java

Tags: java, regex

Using java how can i fetch matcher groups for below strings

1. "https://123343/v1/a/b/"
2. "https://123343/v1/a/b/c/d"

Regex pattern that i used, but didn't work

```
String s = "https://123/v1/a/b/"
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("https:\/\/(.*?)\/v(.*?)\/((?:([^\/]+))\/)+").matcher(s);
matcher.find();
matcher.groupCount() --> gives 4 which is correct
matcher.group(1) --> 123 correct
matcher.group(2) --> 1 correct
matcher.group(3) --> b\ wrong, need 'a'
matcher.group(4) --> b correct
```

Similarly for 2nd string groupcount should be 6 and matcher.group(5)=c and matcher.group(6)=d

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You can not get separate repeated capture group values in Java repeating the capture group itself. That will only capture the value of the last iteration.

What you might do is make use of the `\G` anchor, and get capture group 1, capture group 2, and then all the letters a, b, c, d etc... in capture group 3.

```
(?:https://(\S*?)/v(\S*?)/|\G(?!^))([^/\s]+)/?
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternatives

  - `https://` Match literally
  - `(\S*?)` Capture **group 1**, match optional non whitespace chars
  - `/v` Match literally
  - `(\S*?)` Capture **group 2**, match optional non whitespace chars
  - `/` Match literally
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert the current position at the end of the previous match, not at the start
- `)` Close the non capture group
- `([^/\s]+)` Capture **group 3**, match 1+ characters other than `/` or a whitespace char
- `/?` Match an optional `/`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GmHRKP/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/DIl7hF)

Example

```
String regex = "(?:https:\\/\\/(\\S*?)\\/v(\\S*?)\\/|\\G(?!^))([^/\\s])(?:/|$)";
String string = "https://123/v1/a/b/";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        String grp = matcher.group(i);
        if (grp != null) {
            System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + grp);  
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
Group 1: 123
Group 2: 1
Group 3: a
Group 3: b
```

---

Or a bit more precise match:

```
(?:https://(\d+)/v[a-z]*(\d+)/|\G(?!^))([a-z]+)/?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hqGuyt/1)

Comment: It helped but, any other cleaner way? I need to extract these capture groups and set to a pojo

Answer (score 0):

> *"... how can i fetch matcher groups for below strings ..."*

Here is the *RFC* for a *URI*, which defines the *HTTPS scheme*, path syntax.
*[RFC 3986 – Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax – 3.3.  Path](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3.3)*.

And, here is the related *[ABNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form)*.

```
path-absolute = "/" [ segment-nz *( "/" segment ) ]
segment-nz    = 1*pchar
segment       = *pchar
pchar         = unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"
unreserved    = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
pct-encoded   = "%" HEXDIG HEXDIG
sub-delims    = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")" / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="
```

With that, just split the value.
Here is an example.

```java
String[] s = "https://123343/v1/a/b/c/d".substring(8).split("/");
```

If you wanted to use a *regex*, try the following.
You'll need to remove the *scheme*, and `://`, values.

```
[^/]+(?=/|$)
```

```java
String s = "https://123343/v1/a/b/c/d".substring(8);
List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^/]+(?=/|$)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) l.add(m.group());
```

Output

```
[123343, v1, a, b]
```

```
[123343, v1, a, b, c, d]
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use [`java.net.URI`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) which has getters for various URI-components.

```java
var uri = new URI("https://123/v1/a/b/");

String authority = uri.getAuthority(); // returns 123 
System.out.println(authority);

String path = uri.getPath(); // returns /v1/a/b/
String pathTrimmed = path.replaceAll("^/", "").replaceAll("/$", "");  // trim leading and trailing slashes: v1/a/b
String[] segments = pathTrimmed.split("/");

if (segments.length < 1) return;
System.out.println(segments[0].replaceAll("^v", ""));  // version truncated to number: 1
for (int i=1; i < segments.length; i++) {
  System.out.println(segments[i]);  // remainig segments: a, b, ..
}
```

Run a [demo of this on IDEone](https://ideone.com/eeJ9ny).

See also: [How to obtain the last path segment of a URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050087/how-to-obtain-the-last-path-segment-of-a-uri)