# How to get name of File object without its extension in Java?

Tags: java, string, file, split

I am trying to get name of a `File` object without its extension, e.g. getting "vegetation" when the filename is "vegetation.txt." I have tried implementing this code:

```
openFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
String[] tokens = openFile.getName().split(".");
String name = tokens[0];
```

Unfortunately, it returns a `null` object. There is a problem just in the defining the `String` object, I guess, because the method `getName()` works correctly; it gives me the name of the file with its extension.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you want to implement this yourself, try this:

```
String name = file.getName();
int pos = name.lastIndexOf(".");
if (pos > 0) {
    name = name.substring(0, pos);
}
```

(This variation doesn't leave you with an empty string for an input filename like ".txt".  If you want the string to be empty in that case, change `> 0` to `>= 0`.)

---

You could replace the `if` statement with an assignment using a conditional expression, if you thought it made your code more readable; see @Steven's answer for example.  (I don't think it does ... but it is a matter of opinion.)

---

It is arguably a better idea to use an implementation that someone else has written and tested.  Apache [`FilenameUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#getBaseName(java.lang.String)) is a good choice; see @slachnick's Answer, and also the linked Q&A.

Answer (score 20):

If you don't want to write this code yourself you could use Apache's [FilenameUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#getBaseName(java.lang.String)).

```
FilenameUtils.getBaseName(openFile.getName());
```

This will return the filename minus the path and extension.

Answer (score 5):

I prefer to chop off before the last index of "." to be the filename.
This way a file name: hello.test.txt is just hello.test

i.e.

```
int pos = filename.lastIndexOf(".");
String justName = pos > 0 ? filename.substring(0, pos) : filename;
```

You need to handle there being no extension too.

Answer (score 2):

String#split takes a regex.  "." matches any character, so you're getting an array of empty strings - one for each spot in between each pair of characters.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with your code...

1) Just using "." as an argument to split is being interpreted as a Rejex that you don't want.  You want a literal dot.  So you have to escape it...

```
openFile.getName().split("\\.");
```

2) You will incorrectly parse any file with more than one dot.  The best way to do this is to search for the last dot and get the substring...

```
int pos = openFile.getName().lastIndexOf(".");
if(pos != -1) {
   String name = openFile.getName().substring(0, pos);
}
```

Comment: This should be the best answer for this question.

Comment: does not work if file name contains dot: ```some.a-b.here.txt```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `split("\\.");`. That is, basically escaping the `.` as it's treated as all characters in regex.

Comment: does not work if file name contains dot: ```some.a-b.here.txt```