# Need to extract filename from URL

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to extract a file name with some specific extension from a URL. For example, I have a URL like "https://abc.xyz.com/path/somefilename.xy". I need to extract "somefilename.xy" from the above URL, and nothing else.

basically I need to write that code in my java program

I am not that good in regular expressions, so can somebody help me in that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could also do it without regular expressions like so:

```java
String url = "https://abc.xyz.com/path/somefilename.xy";
String fileName = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
// fileName is now "somefilename.xy"
```

---

EDIT (credit to *@SomethingSomething*): If you should also support urls with parameters, like `https://abc.xyz.com/path/somefilename.xy?param1=blie&param2=bla`, you could use this instead:

```java
String url = "https://abc.xyz.com/path/somefilename.xy?param1=blie&param2=bla";
java.net.Url urlObj = new java.net.Url(url);
String urlPath = urlObj.getPath();
String fileName = urlPath.substring(urlPath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
// fileName is now "somefilename.xy"
```

Comment: You ignore the case when the URL looks like `httt://abc.net/path/to/index.htm?param1=bla&param2=bla`. The result you want is of course `index.htm`, while your code is going to return `index.htm?param1=bla&param2=bla`

Comment: @SomethingSomething Well, the OP asked: "_I need to extract "somefilename.xy" from the above URL, and nothing else._". Also, I answered this over three years ago. I would probably use something like _RyRope_'s answer now. Why re-invent the wheel when there are already libraries and utils that do exactly what you want and have thought about these kind of edge-cases you mentioned.

Comment: Anyway - the trick is adding two lines: `URL urlObj = new URL(url);` and then `String urlPath = urlObj.getPath()`. Then applying your `substring` solution on `urlPath` would be more robust

Comment: For sample. for `httt://abc.net/path/to/index.htm?param1=bla&param2=bla` , the method`URL.getPath()`  will return `/path/to/index.htm`. This is the exact input you want for your `substring` solution

Comment: @SomethingSomething Edited the post (and credited you of course).

Answer (score 2):

This has been done a hundred times, taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605696/get-file-name-from-url):

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;

public class FilenameUtilTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String url = "http://www.example.com/some/path/to/a/file.xml";

        String baseName = FilenameUtils.getBaseName(url);
        String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(url);

        System.out.println("Basename : " + baseName);
        System.out.println("extension : " + extension);
    }

}
```