# Zapier Java Script TypeError: inputData.lastIndexOf is not a function

Tags: zapier

I am trying to extract the file name from an url;

I don't think I can do this via formater so I am trying java script. I have been attempting to make this code work;
[Need to extract filename from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26508424/need-to-extract-filename-from-url)

```
String url = "https://abc.xyz.com/path/somefilename.xy";
String fileName = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
// fileName is now "somefilename.xy"
```

But I'm having no joy. I have cleared numerous other errors using this code;

```
    var output = inputData.substring(inputData.lastIndexOf('/') +1);
    console.log(output);
```

However I keep getting the error "TypeError: inputData.lastIndexOf is not a function" from Zapier after testing.

Any and all advice welcome.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`lastIndexOf` is a string method, while `inputData` is an object. You need to reference your input by name, like so: `inputData.someKey.lastIndexOf('/')`. `someKey` depends on how you set up your code step- it'll be on the left, above the code textarea.